# Align date ticks on x axis

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to use minPadding or maxPadding on a line chart when having set min and max values?

I have a x axis that looks like this:

```
 xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
                month: '%e. %b',
                year: '%b'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Date'
            },
            min: Date.UTC(1970, 9, 21),
            max: Date.UTC(1971, 5, 3),
            minPadding: 0.2
        },
```

minPadding dosen't seem to work as expected. My goal is to try to align date ticks on a line chart and a column chart.

Example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/gtx21hhx/1/

Answer (score 2):

It's always tricky getting lines and columns on two different charts to line up.

There are two different approaches I mighty use to solve this:

1) Add a dummy `column` series to the line chart, with no data. This will force the alignment.

2) Instead of two charts, make this one chart, with two vertically stacked y axes, then the alignment will default to the column alignment.

Also, make sure you have the same `leftMargin` if you are going to stick with two charts - of your x axes don't start at the same point, they won't ever be aligned.

Here's an example with a dummy series:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/gtx21hhx/4/

And here's an example of how you can set up multiple y axes on the same chart:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/py5cznd7/2/